# http web request from batch file

Tags: batch-file, httpwebrequest

I need to execute a http web request from Plesk's Task Scheduler (using shared hosting on Windows/ASP.NET; no Powershell, whatsoever). Thought about using a batch file for this.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Take a look at [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/).  It's a cross-platform command-line tool for making web requests (similar to wget if you've used that before).  You should be able to call that from your batch file.

Answer (score 24):

Without external binaries - only the built-in windows capabilities -> https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/winhttpjs.bat

This is `jscript/.bat` hybrid and can be called like simple bat.
Example usage (I've used http://requestb.in/ for test purposes):

```
  call winhttpjs.bat "http://requestb.in/xxxxxx" -method POST -header hdrs.txt -reportfile reportfile2.txt
   
  call winhttpjs.bat "http://requestb.in/xxxxxx" -method GET -header hdrs.txt -reportfile reportfile3.txt -saveTo c:\somezip.zip 

  call winhttpjs.bat "http://requestb.in/xxxxxx" -method POST -header hdrs.txt -reportfile reportfile2.txt -saveTo responsefile2 -ua "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36"  -body-file some.json
```

Header files format should look like (if passed with `-header` command argument):

```
Header-1: Value-1
ExampleHeader: Value2
```

Does not support multi-part requests (though I'm planning to add such a feature (some day))

Comment: Simple and nice. I applied this in a case where we couldn't install exes.

Comment: Any example for POST with some input fields or files?

Answer (score 4):

You can try using [wget for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm).

Answer (score 4):

What *are* you allowed to install? Could you use [wget for Windows](http://www.christopherlewis.com/WGet/WGetFiles.htm) for instance? Or write a .NET executable which does everything you need it to using WebClient or HttpWebRequest?

Comment: I am thinking about writing a .net app, but have been hoping that there's an easy way to do it from a batch file.

Comment: Hai @ThomasDanecker have u achieved this by batch script, if so please let me know here.

I am looking to post request a url from batch script. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest either [wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) or [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/download.html).  Win32 versions are available for both.

Answer (score 0):

The "curl" utiliity which is basically a command line wrapper for the wonderful libcurl library will handle almost any http request or response. Its freely available for free.