# opening a page through cmd,exe but have cmd.exe stay in focus

Tags: android, windows, cmd

I have a few people using scanners to scan a barcode. The scanners are set with  aprefix - `start "" http://www.stackoverflow.com/scan?` - Then the actual scan - `123456` - then a suffix - `the users id.` .

This leaves me with a finished input through the scanner of

```
start "" http://www.stackoverflow.com/scan?123456&user=123456
```

Going through the `Start` command I am actually opening a seperate program and opening the url through there. This URL though has no visual return - it just sets a flag in a database - and I need the command prompt to stay opened so that I can continually scan items. I could set the webpage o auto close after load but that could potentially block a new input into the command prompt until the browser is closed and the command prompt brought back in to focus.

Is there a better option then `start` that will allow me to hit the webpage but to stay in command prompt.

Note: Attempting to have this done on a windows machine but am open to doing it through android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is already answered in this thread [http web request from batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/420646/http-web-request-from-batch-file)

Code example

```
curl http://www.stackoverflow.com/scan?123456&user=123456
```

So your can replace start "" with the curl executable.

Curl is a cross platform application and there is a windows binary located at [curl download page.](http://curl.haxx.se/download.html)

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I just tried this and seems that I would need to have this installed. 
While this is a perfectly good way to get this done.. and I should have waited before jumping in my pants I found a little nifty program called http-ping which does exactly what I was after.

Comment: link to program I ended up using - http://www.coretechnologies.com/products/http-ping/

Answer (score 0):

if you want analysis content of web page or log in to any site through shell you use  `Invoke-WebRequest`[help](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/3e3dac17-3373-4d22-a54a-9d56a4a556c3(v=wps.630).aspx)
in cmd you can use

```
powershell -command Invoke-WebRequest http://www.stackoverflow.com
```

you can parsing html web page [like](http://woshub.com/parsing-html-webpages-with-powershell/)