# Batch file to get HTTP/S webserver info

Tags: apache, http, batch-file, https, telnet

I am looking for a batch script file which will automatically telnet to a user input website on port 80 and 443 and get us the Server: value (Info).

Below script:

```
telnet -f ip.txt %ip% 80
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: %ip%
for /F "delims=" %%c in ('type ip.txt ^| findstr Server:') do set server=%%c
```

This script does the job but need to enter Ctrl+C to close the session, I need something which will automatically close the connection and get me the output.

I also require help with openssl.exe with the same requirement to check TCP 443 (HTTPS) websites.

Using openssl.exe, I need loop or nested for checking sslv3, tls1.0 - 1.2. Any help with this is highly appreciated.

Comment: take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29432481/388389)

Comment: As I commented on your other post:  WGET or CURL would be more appropriate tools to use and should meet your needs when wrapped with a bat file.

Comment: You would need a telnet client that can be scripted.  The telnet client baked into Windows cannot be scripted but there is one on the web that you can download and use for free.

Comment: @selbie, Thank you very much for your response but with the curl I am not able to pass IP address with HTTPS socket.

I do agree curl and telnet for HTTP socket sends HEAD / HTTP/1.1 request but for HTTPS socket curl expects me to send domain name which matches in the server certificate but openssl does not expect me to enter the domain name. It does accept IP address for HTTPS socket.

Any thoughts??? Thanks in advance.


Regards,

Man

Comment: @Squashman, can you please help me with that software name?

Comment: wget and findstr not working as combination.

I have used --> wget.exe -S https://google.com >> man.txt