# Read JSON response through Windows Script

Tags: json, windows, batch-file

I need to fire a URL through windows script and read the response which is JSON.

For example I need to read the "status" node.

```
<code>{"responseHeader":{"status":0,"QTime":0},"initArgs":["defaults",   ["config","data-config.xml"]],"command":"status","status":"idle","importResponse":"","statusMessages":{},"WARNING":"This response format is experimental.  It is likely to change in the future."} </code>
```

Is it possible through Windows script.

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29432481/388389)

Comment: here's a way to parse a [json with batch](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31701057/388389)